# Calculatig max vertical distance between top and bottom pixels

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix (25x25 pixels) comprised of 0,1 values. I have to calculate the max vertical distance(in pixels) between the top and bottom pixes represented by '1'. I am new to R, so I am unsure how to process this. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below

```
diff(range(which(mat == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)[,"row"]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply! I have to load in a csv file, which contains a handwritten alphabet letter, 1 = black pixel, 0 = white. So will this code iterate through the rows and find the max vertica distance? apologies, just trying to understand the code for future reference and commeting. Thanks E

Comment: @etdoh `which` returns the indices of value `1`, and we just need to focus on the `"row"` information. `range` gives the min and max values, and `diff` computes the difference between min and max.

Comment: Thats brilliant, thanks for the clarification. I need to do the same but for width. I take it itll be the same function, only replacing row with column?

Comment: @etdoh Yes, exactly.

Comment: See where you have "row" should that be the index for said rows "[0:24]" for example.

Comment: @etdoh "row" is the column name of matrix returned from `which`. You can type `?which` to see what's that.